# How to set environment variables and call a perl script with parameters in python subprocess.popen?

Tags: python, perl, batch-file, cmd, subprocess

I'd like to have a method to do 3 things at the same time:

1. Create a subprocess that run the vsvars32.bat (visual studio batch file)
2. In this subprocess set the environment variables.For example in a cmd lines:

   > - SET MYDIR = C:\This\this\here
   > - SET DIR = %MYDIR%
   > - SET PATH = %DIR%\bin;%PATH%
3. Also into this subprocess call the perl script with his parameters. in cmd:

> - cd %MYDIR%\SOURCE\FILES
> - My_Perl.pl -Name Mac -owner -details -vs_version 2005 -Run_type rebuild

I created a code in python:

> myenv = {'MYDIR' : 'C:\This\this\here',
>       'DIR' : '%MYDIR%',
>       'PATH' : '%DIR%\bin;%PATH%'}
>
> batchCmd = 'c:/.../vsvars32.bat'
>
> perlCmd = 'c:/.../MyPerl.pl'
>
> perlValues = ['-Name', 'Mac', '-owner', '-details', '-vs_version', '2005', '-Run_type', 'rebuild']
>
> process = subprocess.Popen(['cmd','/c', batchCmd ,'&&', perlCmd, perlValues], shell=False, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, env = myenv)

The problem is that the function subprocess.popen not recognize myenv values and the perlValues.

Comment: And what is the error message you got?  Please always provide the full traceback.

Comment: "ERROR: Can't locate FileX.pl in %MYDIR%/files/scripts at C:\...\MyPerl.pl line 317."                                        *Show %% instead the real Path = DIR+/files/scripts. and the file is in this directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding perl.exe to perl cmd.

```
perlCmd = 'C:\perl\perl.exe c:/.../MyPerl.pl'
```

Second, you use backslash for path in one place, slash in the other. That maybe a problem.

```
 myenv = {'MYDIR' : 'C:\This\this\here', using backslash
 '%DIR%\bin;%PATH%'} using slash
```

Simply try to print out the env, to see that the environment is populated or not:

```
 process = subprocess.Popen(['cmd','/c', 'set'], shell=False, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, env = myenv)
```

Also, you forgot to cd before executing perl script.

```
process = subprocess.Popen(['cmd','/c', batchCmd ,'&&', 'cd %MYDIR%\SOURCE\FILES', '&&', perlCmd, perlValues], shell=False, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, env = myenv)
```

regards,